How to solve MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite) in flutter?
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite))

I have stuck withh flutter and tflite :
 loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: 'assets/model_unquant.tflite',
      labels: 'assets/labels.txt',
    );
  }


I used latest version
  tflite: ^1.1.2

I try downgrade but not possible

Try running "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get".
Stop the running application and re-run.

run the following commands on your project terminal:

stopping the app
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

